# Using windows(c++) functions in java

Tags: java, c++, windows, system

I used to program in c++(Windows Programming). In that time controlling the system was easy. But now when I have changed to java it seems different.
Please help me with a method to use windows functions like "" in java.

I found something like this [C-JNI wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), but I dont know how to use it..

I would like to get this code in it :

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
```

The c++ code looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()

{

SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: JNI is effing terrible. Use JNA instead, it comes with a set of OS API wrappers already: https://github.com/twall/jna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not resist against JNI. You should (have to) use it.

It's a standard way to access native resources such as APIs.

[Here is a very simple step-by-step tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html), it just has 4 steps and I promise you can learn it less than 30 minutes.

Comment: JNI is the JDBC of FFI. It's a "call-level" interface with no higher level abstractions in sight and the only thing it's good for is to be wrapped in something less frustrating.